# How can I easily remaster Ubuntu?

Tags: remastersys

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to customize live Ubuntu CD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48535/how-to-customize-live-ubuntu-cd)

I'm planning to run an Ubuntu event in my office in which I have to distribute a modified version of Ubuntu which contains all the multimedia content & some specific packages from repositories. How can do it easily? I have a working fresh installation of Ubuntu in my personal computer.