# Software to make a custom live CD?

Tags: cd, customization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to easy remaster ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5458/how-to-easy-remaster-ubuntu)

I'm looking for a list of a free easy to use program to create custom live CDs I can find something like this? I've tried recontructor but it didn't support everything I wanted and it wasn't 100% free.

Please limit one piece of software per answer and include reasons why you think it's good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you should try something like this http://www.debuntu.org/how-to-customize-your-ubuntu-live-cd

Comment: Thanks but I have already used that method, I guess I will just build a python or bash script for it to make it simpler.

Answer (score 0):

What about Remastersys: http://www.geekconnection.org/remastersys/