# How do I install programs in a Ubuntu 12.04 live cd or live usb?

Tags: installation, live-usb, live-cd

Ubuntu 12.04 live cd or live usb. How do I install programs.

Boot/OS and (optionally) configuration [in a tarball] are stored on read-only media.

Any approach recommended? Maybe a good tool that would do the trick.

Comment: You must mount your drives first I would recommend you use G-parted to mount the drives

Comment: Try making your own live cd with the apps you want http://askubuntu.com/questions/5679/software-to-make-a-custom-live-cd or try this one http://askubuntu.com/questions/5458/how-can-i-easily-remaster-ubuntu "remastersys" seems to be the gui of choice for this

Answer (score 1):

- If you have Internet connection you can download the soft that you want to and install it.
  See [the APT-GET guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/apt-get.html).
- If you shutdown the computer, this programs that you have been installed will not be the next time that you turn it. But there is a way to make a partition in the HDD or something like that (I never did that). See [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/20502/62483) where are four answers about that.
- If you don't have Internet connection there is another way to install soft. You have to download it from another computer to the USB and then install it to the off-line computer. See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/160634/62483).

Hope this helps.