# How do I add content to an ISO image?

Tags: iso, cd-image

I have 10.10 cd iso image. I want to add ubuntu manual to this iso image such that, after burning this iso image to cd, in live cd mode and after installation that ubuntu manual should appear in the desktop. I am using acetoneISO.
I wanted to know the location in iso image where to add the manual.

Comment: [This question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5458/how-to-easy-remaster-ubuntu) should point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to extract not only the CD image (iso) but also the squashfs which contains all the system files, please see this guide for remastering ubuntu cds:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization