# How do I integrate a folder into an ISO image?

Tags: 10.10, iso

I just can't seem to figure this out. I tried AcetonISO, but the file is only 43MB (the folder is ~ 800MB). I also tried a Windows tool called ImgBurn, but same thing happened. How can I add the folder to a bootable ISO image, (it's a remastered Ubuntu)?

Comment: The process of constructing an ISO image of a bootable live CD is not quite the same as simply creating an ISO from the contents of a folder. The answers to [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5458/how-to-easy-remaster-ubuntu) explain a couple of methods for working with live CD images.

Comment: yeah , i read the documentation but it makes references to 9.04 and earlier, however, i managed to edit everything but  im stuck at building the iso, no matter what , and how i put it the outcome is the same,i can't build the iso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should follow the 'How to Remaster Ubuntu' guide that ændrük has pointed to in his comment:

[How can I easily remaster Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5458/how-to-easy-remaster-ubuntu)

It explains how to get the folder into an iso image and also how to make the cd bootable (very important for a remastered ubuntu cd). For a normal CD, you need only use bresaro burning software, drag the files inside the folder onto a data cd and then save the cd as an iso (by default if you don't have a burnable cd in the drive, this is what Brasero will offer):

[image]