# Grub only finding the first 26 drives

Tags: grub2

Installing grub2 fails on my system (10.4 64Bit) with:

```
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: cannot find a GRUB drive for /dev/sdaq1.  
 Check your device.map.
```

Checking device.map, it only lists hd0 to hd25 corresponding to sda to sdz. Recreating the device map produces the same result. How do I get grub to recognize /dev/sdaq1.

Note: The machine has many, many devices; sdaq is the correct drive.

Answer (score 8):

You need to patch grub-installer.

See [bug report 776633](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub-installer/+bug/776633) for a [patch](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/71019804/many-disks.patch):

```
Index: grub-installer-1.60ubuntu3/grub-installer
===================================================================
--- grub-installer-1.60ubuntu3.orig/grub-installer  2011-05-03 12:00:57.553509999 -0700
+++ grub-installer-1.60ubuntu3/grub-installer   2011-05-03 12:04:02.873000831 -0700
@@ -286,7 +286,7 @@
     /dev/loop)
    disc_offered_devfs="$bootfs"
    ;;
-    /dev/[hsv]d[a-z]|/dev/xvd[a-z]|/dev/cciss/c[0-9]d[0-9]*|/dev/ida/c[0-9]d[0-9]*|/dev/rs/c[0-9]d[0-9]*|/dev/mmcblk[0-9]|/dev/ad[0-9]*|/dev/da[0-9]*)
+    /dev/[hsv]d[a-z]|/dev/[sv]d[a-z][a-z]|/dev/[sv]d[a-z][a-z][a-z]|/dev/xvd[a-z]|/dev/cciss/c[0-9]d[0-9]*|/dev/ida/c[0-9]d[0-9]*|/dev/rs/c[0-9]d[0-9]*|/dev/mmcblk[0-9]|/dev/ad[0-9]*|/dev/da[0-9]*)
    disc_offered_devfs="$prefix"
    ;;
     *)
```

grub-installer is probably not on your system (since after it's in installed there's not really need for it to stay ;) ). This is the package it concerns: http://packages.ubuntu.com/source/natty/grub-installer so you'll probably find it on the install medium...

Here's a quick how to on remastering your own CD:  [How can I easily remaster Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5458/how-can-i-easily-remaster-ubuntu)

Comment: Sounds like the right direction. I'm however not sure how to apply the patch: I tried to install grub2 with apt-get install and there does not seem to be a file with name grub-installer
on my system when doing this.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info. In my case the problem occurred during a kernel upgrade, not a new installation, on a system that has a lot of staff installed and is running in a semi-production environment. So, I'd rather not do a re-install if at all possible.