# "Merge" or "Slipstream" Wine into Ubuntu LiveCD

Tags: 11.10, wine

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I easily remaster Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5458/how-can-i-easily-remaster-ubuntu)

I must say Ubuntu Linux is the easiest OS I have ever seen.
With Linux I really am the "boss" of my computer.

I was thinking: Can I put Wine in the Ubuntu 11.10 Desktop ISO?
So when I pop in the live cd and install it, Wine is automatically there, installed and usable.
Wine is the first thing I install after my Ubuntu setup.
This option would make everything so easier for me.

Thank you all and keep Linux alive! :D

Comment: Adding to the dupe Ubuntu Customization Kit is an easy to use tool to customize livecds, Customizer is another great tool.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah it is possible.
use uck (available in softwarecentre)
you can add extra packages to live cd via uck
if you want to backup existing system you can use remastersys

Answer (score 0):

When creating a bootable *flash drive* using Ubuntu standard "Startup disk creator" there's an option to allocate some space on the drive to store any changes you made to the system so they persist between reboots. So you can just boot from that drive, install wine and any software you need and they'll be there the next time you use it. The documents in your home folder will also be preserved.

Obviously, this wouldn't work with a CD disk because it's read-only. If you want a CD drive you'll need to follow Aboobacker Mk's advice

Answer (score 0):

Yep, you can do that with Customizer. Customizer is a Ubuntu LiveCD remastering tool light years ahead of uck. It supports installing multiple desktop environments, installing additional packages not included in the default set (what you're looking for), accessing the GUI of the LiveCD through Xeypher, and much more. To install, open a terminal and run the following commands: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa;customizer-dev-team/devel`, `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get install customizer`. Once finished, open Customizer and click "Select ISO". Open an Ubuntu 11.10 ISO, and click "Install Package". Use synaptic to install the wine 1.3 package. One finished, click "Create ISO". Ta Da! Your own custom Ubuntu!