# Can I create a LiveUSB from Ubuntu 12.04 without having the original ISO file?

Tags: live-usb, iso

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I easily remaster Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5458/how-can-i-easily-remaster-ubuntu)

I have 12.04 installed but I would like to create a 12.04 .iso file to put on a USB and run Ubuntu 12.04 of that. I do not want to download the whole 700mb+ file. Any help?

Comment: So you want to create ISO of Already installed Ubuntu 12.04  system to create a bootable media.

Comment: I think Ajay is on a 12.04 system and wants to create a regular LiveUSB BUT he no longer has the ISO and does not want to download it. The answer is no, your only option is to remaster your existing system into an ISO (which will probably have to go on a DVD).

Comment: You can order the LiveCD and create the bootable USB from the CD. Technically, you would not have downloaded the ISO. But is that really answering your question?